# Groovy: not all strings that are equal *are* equal

Tags: groovy

Just encountered an odd weirdo when programming with Groovy:

I was trying to get objects from a HashMap which I had filled with keys that were created using Groovy's "interpolation" feature (i.e. strings in double quotes containing place-holders) - cf. key1 in the example below. Later during processing I was trying to get objects from that map using keys that I had created using a different approach by simply concatenating strings - cf. key2 in the below example. To my surprise I wasn't able to get the expected objects from my map.

I then boild this down to this example:

```
void testGroovyStrings() {
    String foo = "foo"
    String bar = "bar"
    String delim = '#'
    HashMap map = new HashMap();
    
    def key1 = "${foo}${delim}${bar}"  // creating key variant 1

    map.put(key1, new Integer(5))   // putting some object suing the "String" just created

    def key2 = foo + delim + bar; // creating key variant 2
    
    // my expectation was that this should yield the same value as key1 
    // and that I would get back the object that I had entered above. 
    // After all the keys look identical and are treated as "equal":
    System.out.println "key1: '${key1}' - key2: '${key2}'  equal?:${key1 == key2}"
    
    def obj = map.get(key2)       // but this yields null ?!?

    System.out.println "got object: ${obj}"
    
    // only this gave me a clue, why this failed:
    System.out.println "got object: ${key1} (${key1.getClass()}) - ${key2} (${key2.getClass()})"
}
```

This yields the output:

```
key1: 'foo#bar' - key2: 'foo#bar'  equal?:true
got object: null
got object: foo#bar (class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl) - foo#bar (class java.lang.String)
```

Obviously, the HashMap's get()-method does not call the equals()-method on the key-objects but uses some other approach leading to this oddity that keys passing the '==' operator as equals are NOT really equal when used as keys for a (Hash)Map.

One can get this working by converting the interpolated string to a "java.lang.String" like so:

```
def key1 = "${foo}${delim}${bar}".toString()
```

... but this looks so ugly and verbose. :-(

My question: is this (not) working by design or did I miss some (compiler-)setting or is there a way to fix this? Or should I file a bug with the Groovy runtime? Other suggestions?

Comment: You can work around this problem using Groovy's subscript operator: `map[key1] = 5`. Then, `assert map[key2] == 5`.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using Groovy templated strings as keys for maps

In your example, `key1` is a GString (templated Groovy String)

And `key2` is a String

if you switch to

```
    def key1 = "${foo}${delim}${bar}".toString()  // creating key variant 1
```

It should work as you expect.

Saw the edit where you say you know this :-)

This is working by design, it's a quirk of Groovy Strings that they do not make good map keys.  There's no compiler setting, and there's no point raising an issue as there's lots already.

Comment: Well - looking at the HashMap's code I'ld say, if the GStringImpl provided a decent hash() method that would yield the same result as the corresponding String.hash() method then things would be fine. But for some odd reason it's parent class GString defines hashCode() as ```    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 37 + toString().hashCode();
    }``` which seems to spoil things... Beats me what this `37 +` is supposed to improve here.

Comment: Even better: When I define `key1` as `String key1 = ...` then things works fine (probably that's because it then does that `.toString()` implicitly). It's only because I had used `def key1 = ...` here (or rather: in the original code I had used that GroovyString directly as first argument to the `put()`-method), that this fails.

Comment: You're walking a well trodden path: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-1959 and it may be fixed in Groovy 5 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-8212

Comment: why the map literal keys are not amended with `toString()` automatically, unless other than `String` key type is specified (if any)?